# unable to login magento connect manager

Tags: magento-connect

Hi i've tried to login the admin dash with the user/password 
but unable to login to magento connect using the same credential , 
even tried to add another administrator user but unable to login. 
The error is when i login @ the downloader page , 
it will reload to the same downloader login page with this error downloader/index.php?A= at the address bar... 
any kind soul able to assist?

Comment: Would you mind formatting your post better? As it currently stands this feels like a wall of text.

Comment: if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

Instead of using HTTPS, use HTTP:

For example: http://xxxx.com/downloader/index.php